# Rebol anonymous function behavior is weird

Tags: functional-programming, rebol

My anonymous func test below is executed only once:

```
repeat i 5 [
  func[test][
    print test
  ] rejoin ["test" i]
]
```

I am obliged to name it to be able to execute it 5 times as expected:

```
repeat i 5 [
  test: func[test][
    print test
  ] test rejoin ["test" i]
]
```

This is weird. isn't it really possible to use anonymous function in loops ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first code example simply **defines** the anonymous function five times. It does not invoke it. Add a **do** and all should be well:

```
repeat i 5 [
  do func[test][
    print test
  ] rejoin ["test" i]
]

test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
```